# Python script didn't show nodemcu data on raspberry pi (raspberry role is mqtt broker)

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, raspberry-pi3

Sorry for my bad english. 
I install mqtt(mosquitto) on raspberry pi 3 and send nodemcu data to broker. when I write 'mosquitto_sub -d -t tester' in terminal it shows nodemcu data, but I have a python3 script that runs when I run but does not show anything and i don't know what is problem

nodemcu code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 
#include <PubSubClient.h> 

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* wifi_password = "wifi_password";


const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.103";
const char* mqtt_topic = "/tmp/room";
const char* clientID = "123";

WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server, 1883, wifiClient); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (client.connect(clientID)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to MQTT Broker!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection to MQTT Brokers pressed down");
    // (i.e. if the state of the b failed...");
  }

}

void loop() {
 char ldr_value [10] = {'b', 'd', 'l', 't', 'd'};

  delay(5000);
  client.publish(mqtt_topic, ldr_value);
}
```

python3 script:

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
    mqtt_topic = "/tmp/room"
    mqtt_broker_ip = "localhost"
    client = mqtt.Client()

    def on_connect(client, userdata, rc):
        print("Connected!", str(rc))
        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic)

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print("Topic: ", msg.topic + "\nMessage: " + str(msg.payload))

    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(mqtt_broker_ip, 1883)
    client.loop_forever()
    client.disconnect()
```

I delete include_dir line in
/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf and write linstener 1883

My os : 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch

Comment: You have said you use 'mosquitto_sub -d -t tester' to print nodemcu data. By python client is subscribing to /tmp/room  topic. Both seems to be different. Are using the correct topic in python client ?

Comment: I edit text again. Yes i use same topic /tmp/room

Comment: Can you try remove the disconnect line in python code and try ?

Comment: MQTT topics really shouldn't start with a leading `/`

Comment: I test both with / and without /. The script is not response to both

Answer (score 0):

The on_connect method you are using is not correct. I have modified your codes and tested it. It works

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client = mqtt.Client("123")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected!", str(rc))
  client.subscribe("test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   print("Topic: ", msg.topic + "\nMessage: " + str(msg.payload))

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: It is just show connected message not any more and by every reset the nodemcu it repeat connected message